# Scale qplot stacked bar chart to the same height

Tags: r, ggplot2

I run the following code to get a stacked bar chart of my data

```
qplot(factor(course.name):factor(condition):factor(condition.player),data=dfAll,geom="bar",fill=factor(textbook.usage.distribution))
```

[image]

I want to scale each bar to the same hight, but keep the proportion of the stacks the same. It should become something like this :[image]

How can I achieve that? I tried

```
   + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

But it does not scale the bars to the same height, and the percentage seems to be based on the total number of A+B+C+D of all observations.

Comment: Check [`position_fill`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_fill.html)

Comment: Could [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376079/2-level-groups-with-ggplot2/18416431#18416431) be it (only without facetting)?

Comment: @Henrik Thanks, finally I use geom_bar(position="fill") with ggplot to make it work. It does not work with qplot

Comment: @nan, glad to hear that it worked. `qplot` code may be `q`uicker to  _type_ in some instances, but in my opinion it is much better to try to learn the `ggplot` syntax right away. Good luck!